# Link report files for Flex with multiple modules overwrite each other

Tags: flexbuilder

I am using the link-report option in Flex Builder 3 to try to track down dependencies in my Flex application's modules.

However a different report is generated for each module and they all use the same filename so they end up overwriting each other!

Is there a way to generate separate files for each module - without having to create a filewatcher to copy them each as they are generated!

I am using the following command line arguments :

`-locale en_US -link-report=linkreport.xml -optimize`

Ideally I'd like something like `-locale en_US -link-report=linkreport_%MODULE%.xml -optimize` but i dont know if that is possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm running into the exact same problem now myself.

Comment: i'm afraid i gave up. the link report didnt yield as useful information as i thought i was going to and i never persued this further. in fact i havent done any flex/as3 work in about 9 months. good luck )

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this is annoying, and should be supported by the compiler.

A not-so-elegant approach (assuming that your modules and main swf are all in the same project), is to create a project, and point the source folder back to the source folder of the existing project, but with a different output folder.

Now compile only the module, and you should be able to get the link report for just the module.

Crummy approach, but useful for getting-er-done when trying to track down leaking references.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using dependent modules . If you use independent modules then they will have there own classes and do not share with the main application and that may give you the desired results .